# NDK error: use of undeclared identifier '__min'

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have tested with min and __min and in all cases it puts me that it is not declared. Does anyone know where it can come from?

[image]

```
 if(x1 > 0 && x2 >0)
   sol = __min(x1,x2);
   //sol=min(x1,x2);
else
  if(x1<0 && x2 <0)
     sol = -1; 
  else
    if(x1 > 0)
        if(coefA > 0)
          if(x1>MIXMIN)
            sol=-2;    
          else
            sol = x1;
        else
            if(x1 > LIMITEQMAX)
                sol=-2;    
            else
                sol = x1;
    else
       if(x2>MIXMIN)
           if(coefA > 0)
               if(x2>MIXMIN)
                  sol=-2;  
               else
                 sol = x2;
           else
               if(x2>LIMITEQMAX)
                   sol=-2;
               else
                   sol=x2;
return sol;
```

}

Comment: What about `std::min`?

Comment: Please avoid pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**math.h** declares

```
double  fmin(double, double)
```

This is the best you can find in system headers except STL.

Comment: Please don't recommend deprecated functionality to newbies.